# Difference-in-difference estimation with a logistic regression line

Tags: difference-in-difference

I'm analyzing a welfare subsidy, where the goal is to estimate the effect of the subsidy on salary and hours worked. To do this I am trying to make a difference-in-difference estimator. However, the two dependent variables I wish to analyze are categorical variables. Is it possible to use DiD when this is the case, as the model isn't linear? And if so, how do I code this in STATA?

Comment: A somewhat comprehensive example using R may be found [here](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) in Section 2.8.  This incorporates a nonlinear long-term trend plus seasonality.  This is for a count variable for Y.   You would use exactly the same approach for a categorical Y just using a different fitting function in place of the `Glm` call.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have interval outcome panel data, so a logit is inappropriate. I would suggest you try [`xtintreg`](https://www.stata.com/manuals/xtxtintreg.pdf) with a Chamberlain Mundlak device to relax the random coefficient assumption and allow fixed effects.

If the bins are fairly uniform in width and narrow, then the usual continuous regression approach might not be too terrible.